# How does KVM schedule multiple VMs in Intel VMX?

Tags: linux, x86, virtualization, kvm

I am studying Intel VMX through Linux KVM.
And I could NOT clearly understand how does KVM (Linux) schedule multiple VMs running cocurrently in the same host.
For example, there is 1 physical CPU in the host, and there are 2 KVM VMs, each configured with 1 vCPU.
Once they are started, KVM/QEMU configure a VMCS for each vCPU, so there are 2 VMCSes in KVM. Since there is only 1 pCPU, so KVM/Linux has to schedule each vCPU 1 by 1.
My understanding is when vCPUa is running, KVM VMPTRLD VMCS of vCPUa, and run the VM's codes. Then, vCPUb is to be scheduled, KVM will VMPTRST VMCS of vCPUa to somewhere, and VMPTRLD VMCS of vCPUb from somewhere.
By reading KVM's code, I did NOT find where VMPTRLD/VMPTRST happened for vCPU scheduling, and what is 'somewhere'.

Comment: I'd guess that KVM works like a process under the host kernel, getting scheduled by the regular scheduler.  It must need code for switching between running a guest VM vs. running host code (including non-VM user-space processes on the host).  Did you already look at context-switching functions to see if they're KVM-aware?

Comment: That makes sense, and that is also my guess.   I have to dig into scheduler code for details, will update my findings here.

Answer (score 2):

vmptrld is in vmx_vcpu_load in arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c
vmresume is in vmx_vcpu_run

Comment: It’s a bit hard to follow because all the code to support nested virtualization is in the same file, so most of the references to vmptrld and vmresume are related to operations being done by the guest VMM.

Comment: Note that vmptrst is not needed, because the VMCS pointer stays the same as the value that was loaded.

Comment: So, what about scheduling other VMs on this pCPU, or migrate a vCPU to another pCPU, which has to change active/current VMCS on pCPU?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, KVM will register two callouts for vCPU schedule in and out, like below.
`kvm_preempt_ops.sched_in = kvm_sched_in;`
`kvm_preempt_ops.sched_out = kvm_sched_out;`

So, each time, when scheduling happens (have not deeply dived into this), they are called. Take `kvm_sched_in()` as an example, it will calls,

```c
static void kvm_sched_in(struct preempt_notifier *pn, int cpu)
{
    struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu = preempt_notifier_to_vcpu(pn);

    if (vcpu->preempted)
        vcpu->preempted = false;

    kvm_arch_sched_in(vcpu, cpu);

    kvm_arch_vcpu_load(vcpu, cpu);
}
```

And `kvm_arch_vcpu_load()` will play with VMCS, like below.

```c
void kvm_arch_vcpu_load(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu, int cpu)
{
    /* Address WBINVD may be executed by guest */
    if (need_emulate_wbinvd(vcpu)) {
        if (kvm_x86_ops->has_wbinvd_exit())
            cpumask_set_cpu(cpu, vcpu->arch.wbinvd_dirty_mask);
        else if (vcpu->cpu != -1 && vcpu->cpu != cpu)
            smp_call_function_single(vcpu->cpu,
                    wbinvd_ipi, NULL, 1);
    }
    kvm_x86_ops->vcpu_load(vcpu, cpu); <<======
```

Since,     `.vcpu_load = vmx_vcpu_load,`

```c
/*
 * Switches to specified vcpu, until a matching vcpu_put(), but assumes
 * vcpu mutex is already taken.
 */
static void vmx_vcpu_load(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu, int cpu)
{
    struct vcpu_vmx *vmx = to_vmx(vcpu);
    u64 phys_addr = __pa(per_cpu(vmxarea, cpu));

    if (!vmm_exclusive)
        kvm_cpu_vmxon(phys_addr);
    else if (vmx->loaded_vmcs->cpu != cpu)
        loaded_vmcs_clear(vmx->loaded_vmcs);

    if (per_cpu(current_vmcs, cpu) != vmx->loaded_vmcs->vmcs) {
        per_cpu(current_vmcs, cpu) = vmx->loaded_vmcs->vmcs;
        vmcs_load(vmx->loaded_vmcs->vmcs);
    }
```

That is it.